# How to create a lazy loading JTree

Tags: java, swing, events, jtree

```
    tree.addTreeExpansionListener(new TreeExpansionListener() {
        @Override
        public void treeExpanded(TreeExpansionEvent event) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) event
                            .getPath().getLastPathComponent();
            node.removeAllChildren();
            //System.out.println(node.getChildCount());
            child = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("new node");
            node.add(child);;

            frame.doLayout();
            frame.repaint();

        }

        @Override
        public void treeCollapsed(TreeExpansionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: You need to notify the `TreeModel`, something like [`JTree#insertNodeInto`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html#insertNodeInto(javax.swing.tree.MutableTreeNode,%20javax.swing.tree.MutableTreeNode,%20int)) and [`TreeModel#removeNodeFromParent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html#removeNodeFromParent(javax.swing.tree.MutableTreeNode)), for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22683092/jtree-avoid-collapse-after-reload/22683989#22683989)

Comment: See the [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/7784) for an example.