# JTree wont update

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I am trying to add a node to my JTree. I do that like so:

```
    DefaultMutableTreeNode root = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) tree.getModel().getRoot();
    DefaultMutableTreeNode newNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(event.getObjectThatHasChanged());
    root.add(newNode);
    ((DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel()).reload();
```

However, the tree itself doesnt update. Ive read [posts](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2495518) that reload() is what you are supposed to call, but to no effect. Also please note this is being called on the EDT. Any ideas?

EDIT:

I have tried this approach:

```
    DefaultMutableTreeNode root = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) tree.getModel().getRoot();
    DefaultMutableTreeNode newNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(event.getObjectThatHasChanged());
    ((DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel()).
            insertNodeInto(newNode, root, root.getChildCount() - 1);
```

Still no go. However, when I shut the program down and reopen it, the new node is there. (I persist my data).

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22683092/jtree-avoid-collapse-after-reload/22683989#22683989)

Comment: @MadProgrammer You use `node.getChildCount())` where as copeg has `node.getChildCount() - 1)` in his example.Can you clarify which is correct?

Comment: @user489041 Java is zero index, so the number of actual nodes is getChildCount - 1. So after you add a node tothe parent mode, you need to reference the last node...

Answer (score 3):

Add nodes to a JTree using the `DefaultTreeModel`'s *insertNodeInto* method. To quote the API

> This will then message nodesWereInserted to create the appropriate event. This is the preferred way to add children as it will create the appropriate event.

For example:

```
((DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel()).insertNodeInto(newNode, root, 0);//inserts at beginning
//((DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel()).insertNodeInto(newNode, root, root.getChildCount() - 1);//inserts at end
```

Comment: I tried this approach, but to no avail. Does the tree perhaps need repainted or revalidated?

Comment: Shouldn't be necessary. Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates this not working?